# Passing a custom deleter to std::unique_ptr with std::function object

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, unique-ptr, std-function

I have the following working code to initialize a `std::unique_ptr` with a custom deleter:

```
class Dataset
{
    ...
private:
    class CustomGDALDatasetDeleter {
    public:
            void operator()(GDALDatasetH res) const {
                ::GDALClose(res);
            }
    };
    using ResourceType = std::unique_ptr<GDALDataset,
                                         CustomGDALDatasetDeleter>;
    ResourceType data;
};
```

Later I have this code:

```
data = ResourceType(static_cast<GDALDataset*>(::GDALOpen(filename.c_str(),
                                              static_cast<GDALAccess>(mode)))
);
```

When I try the same with a `std::function` object and `lambdas` I get a `bad_function_call` exception:

```
class Dataset
{
    ...
private:
    std::function<void (GDALDatasetH)> del = [](GDALDatasetH res){::GDALClose(res);};
    using ResourceType = std::unique_ptr<GDALDataset,
                                         decltype(del)>;
    ResourceType data;

};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are presumably not passing a copy of the deleter to the pointer constructor.

Comment: A way to look at it that might be easier to understand is, how is the compiler supposed to tell from knowing the deleter is `std::function<void (GDALDatasetH)>` to knowing that it needs to call `GDALClose`? There is nothing that contains that information aside from `del` itself, the `unique_ptr` doesn't know anything about `del`.

Comment: Yeah you're right. From what I understand, the reason for the problem is that `std::unqiue_ptr`, when given two template type arguments, tries to default construct an object of the deleter type. But by definition lambda has none, what results in an empty deleter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a polymorphic function wrapper, and **when default-constructing it is constructed empty**.
Thus, it throws an exception on invocation.

> #### `function() noexcept;`
>
> ```
> template <class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a) noexcept;
> ```
>
> 2 Postconditions: `!*this`.

> #### 20.9.11.2.4 function invocation [func.wrap.func.inv]
>
> > ```
> > R operator()(ArgTypes... args) const
> > ```
> >
> > 1 Effects: `INVOKE (f, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)..., R)` (20.9.2), where `f` is the target object (20.9.1) of `*this`.
> >     2 Returns: Nothing if `R` is `void`, otherwise the return value of `INVOKE (f, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)..., R)`.
> >     3 Throws: `bad_function_call` if `!*this`; otherwise, any exception thrown by the wrapped callable object.

Set the deleter before / at the time you first put something into `data`, and all is ok.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I have to admit that I do not fully understand, why the same call with a functor works without specifing the deleter object when constructing the pointer.

Comment: @Meiner: The magic is in what behavior the default-constructed object has: Most functors can work as intended with default-constructed state and don't need to throw an error. Yours probably is even stateless, and will thus be optimized out for ultimate performance.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. I found the corresponding entry in my edition of the `C++ Standard Library` book.